# How to fix Access-Control-Allow-Origin error from a remote site

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to use the service at http://rate-exchange.appspot.com/currency, but all I get is the the Access-Control-Allow-Origin error.

Understanding this is a server problem, and that http://rate-exchange.appspot.com/currency is not my service, I have no idea how to fix this problem.

Using the service like this:

```
$.getJSON("http://rate-exchange.appspot.com/currency", { "from": Currency.From, "to": Currency.To }, function (result) {
    if (!result.err) {
        Currency.Rate = result.rate;
        $("#footer-output").text("All sales in " + Currency.To + " including VAT");
    }
    else {
        $("#footer-output").text("All sales in local currency including VAT");
    }
});
```

Now trying to get this data directly in my browser is not a problem.  Is there anything I can do, or can this only be fixed on the server?

Comment: You can try using jsonp to GET data from the API.

Comment: @Lowkase you're right, [this service](http://rate-exchange.appspot.com/) accepts JSONP requests. You could make this an answer.

Comment: Write at least the correct ajax call...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will work.  I took the liberty of adding a currency object to the code.  That part obviously you are defining elsewhere.

Plunkr:  http://beta.plnkr.co/aMVPVE9kUPPcsD0Ma5s3

Code:

```
$(function(){
 Currency = {};
 Currency.From = "USD";
 Currency.To = "PEN";
 Currency.Rate= 0;
 $.getJSON("http://rate-exchange.appspot.com/currency?callback=?", { "from": Currency.From, "to": Currency.To }, function (result) {
    if (!result.err) {
        Currency.Rate = result.rate;
        $("#footer-output").text("All sales in " + Currency.To + " including VAT");
    }
    else {
        $("#footer-output").text("All sales in local currency including VAT");
    }
});
```

Adding the callback=? to the url and jquery will issue a jsonp request.  Here is the section from the docs (halfway down):  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

JSONP

If the URL includes the string "callback=?" (or similar, as defined by the server-side API), the request is treated as JSONP instead. See the discussion of the jsonp data type in $.ajax() for more details.

Comment: Note that the getJSON will issue a JSONP request when it sees the `callback=?` in the url.

Comment: Genious! All you did was add ?callback=? to the url. Was does it do?

Comment: I've updated the answer to a reference to the docs with regards to the callback.

Answer (score 1):

Using JSONP:

```
Currency = {};
Currency.From = "USD";
Currency.To = "PEN";
Currency.Rate= 0;   
$.get("http://rate-exchange.appspot.com/currency", { "from": Currency.From, "to": Currency.To }, function (result) {
    if (!result.err) {
        Currency.Rate = result.rate;
        $("#footer-output").text("All sales in " + Currency.To + " including VAT");
    }
    else {
        $("#footer-output").text("All sales in local currency including VAT");
    }
}, 'jsonp');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/U6jQG/)